# Bound task in celery is not able to access instance variable in django project

Tags: django, task, celery, background-task

I have setup celery in my django project using official documentation at
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

So my `MyApp/tasks.py` have content

```
from celery import shared_task

class Someclass():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @shared_task(bind=True) 
    def func1(self):
        '''This does not work'''
        return self.x + self.y


    @shared_task(bind=True)
    def func2(self, a, b):
        '''This works well'''
        return a + b
```

When I run

```
In [9]: o = Someclass(3, 4)    
In [10]: o.func1.delay()
Out[10]: <AsyncResult: afc6b151-d71c-4f46-a916-6917f98c681f>
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'func1' object has no attribute 'x'
```

When I run

```
In [11]: o.func2.delay(3, 4)
Out[11]: <AsyncResult: 3b227f00-8d9c-472b-b7d8-8b4b6261f689>
```

This works perfectly

How can I make `func1` working so that it can use instance variables e.g. `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 1):

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(bind=True)
def func(self, a, b):
    return a + b


class Someclass():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def func1(self):
        return func.delay(self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.